# Postgres SQL group by overlapping periods

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, postgresql-9.3, overlap

I try to group data by overlapping periods and keep only the smaller periods if they completely cover a bigger one.

So an example to be clearer.
Let's assume this structure and data

```
drop table chload.testdata
create table chload.testdata
( 
  id int,
  startdate date,  
  enddate date,
  val text
);

insert into chload.testdata (id,startdate,enddate,val) values
-- included periods
(1, to_date('2009-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2010-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), 'incA'),
(2, to_date('2010-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2011-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), 'incB'),
(3, to_date('2011-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2012-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), 'incC'),

-- isolated period
(4, to_date('2008-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2009-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), 'isoD'),

-- Covering periods
(5, to_date('2009-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2011-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), 'covE'),
(6, to_date('2009-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2012-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), 'covF')
;
```

Now the game is to get that result

```
2009-01-01  2010-01-01  incA covE covF
2010-01-01  2011-01-01  incB covE covF
2011-01-01  2012-01-01  incC covF
2008-01-01  2009-01-01  isoD
```

Note: covering periods are not displayed if they are totally «covered» by included periods.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What have you attempted yourself?

Answer (score 1):

try to use used this

```
SELECT distinct lg1.startdate, lg1.enddate, lg1.val || ' '|| lg2.val
  FROM testdata lg1,testdata lg2
where  lg1.enddate<= lg2.enddate and  lg1.startdate>= lg2.startdate and  lg1.id!= lg2.id
order by 3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. It could be a solution. However, I also need to get isolated periods and I could also get many «covering periods». I've just adapted the example to better reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

try to use used this

```
WITH enddates AS
  (SELECT DISTINCT lg1.startdate,
                   lg1.enddate,
                   lg1.val AS pg,
                   string_agg(lg2.val,' ') AS RESULT
   FROM chload.testdata lg1,
        chload.testdata lg2
   WHERE (lg1.enddate<= lg2.enddate
          AND lg1.startdate>= lg2.startdate
          AND lg1.id!= lg2.id
          AND lg1.val NOT IN
            (SELECT lg2.val
             FROM chload.testdata lg1,
                  chload.testdata lg2
             WHERE lg1.enddate<= lg2.enddate
               AND lg1.startdate>= lg2.startdate
               AND lg1.id!= lg2.id))
   GROUP BY 1,
            2,
            3
   ORDER BY 3)
SELECT DISTINCT startdate,
                enddate,
                pg,
                pg||' '|| RESULT AS RESULT
FROM enddates
UNION ALL
SELECT lg.startdate,
       lg.enddate,
       lg.val AS pg,
       lg.val AS RESULT
FROM chload.testdata lg
WHERE lg.val NOT IN
    (SELECT lg1.val
     FROM chload.testdata lg1,
          chload.testdata lg2
     WHERE lg1.enddate<= lg2.enddate
       AND lg1.startdate>= lg2.startdate
       AND lg1.id!= lg2.id)
  AND lg.val NOT IN
    (SELECT lg2.val
     FROM chload.testdata lg1,
          chload.testdata lg2
     WHERE lg1.enddate<= lg2.enddate
       AND lg1.startdate>= lg2.startdate
       AND lg1.id!= lg2.id)
ORDER BY 3
```